# Regex - Jquery to get attribute value based on end of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Need the value of Div content, for this I am using

```
$('div[__jx__id="___$_912__right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser"]').text()
```

Giving successful result.

but the problem is, Initial string of attribute **__jx__id** is always changed to any dynamic number such as $_912 to $_1025...

```
<div class="jx_ui_html_div" __jx__id="___$_912__right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser">Chrome </div>

<div class="jx_ui_html_div" __jx__id="___$_1025__right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser">Chrome </div>
```

How can I use Regex expression to only match end part of string. Here **right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser** is always be fixed but initial is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery endswith attribute selector like following.

```
 $('div[__jx__id$="__right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser"]').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you should use "Selector Reference"
Like this:

```
$('div[__jx__id$="right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser"]').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter() for this , with a regex:

```js
alert($('div.jx_ui_html_div').filter(
function(){
return ($(this).attr('__jx__id')).match(/.*right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser/);

}

).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jx_ui_html_div" __jx__id="___$_912__right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser">Chrome </div>

<div class="jx_ui_html_div" __jx__id="___$_1025__right_panel__details_panel__vBrowser">Chrome </div>
```